# Visual Studio TFS Alerts: How to send out an alert upon successful publish of a web application?

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-alerts

I have taken a look at alerts management for TFS 2012 after installing power tools, and I can see about four types of alert templates:

- Work Item
- Code Review
- Check In
- Build

I was wondering if there was a possibility of having a supported way to register alerts under “Publish” event-type, manageable directly via the Alerts explorer.

If not, I thought of some workarounds:

- If this cannot be done and managed via the Alerts explorer, can I customize an alert to be triggered on Publish event via a Web Service? If so, does the TFS API support such customization?
- I can also instead go with a continuous delivery approach and set an automated publish upon successful build of a solution, with an email alert on Build-Event Success (which would also mean that a solution has been published).

Which approach would be a supported way for setting "on publish"-event alerts for web solutions via TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be not to use the Publish in Visual Studio but instead to use a Build to publish your solution (either triggered on check-in, or manually triggered).  Then you can easily setup an alert on that build.  Using a build instead of VS-Publish is also considered a better practice because it gives you more power and flexibility for the deployment process.

Comment: Each of our Applications have three branches (development, preproduction and production). Can I set the automatic build-publish to only occur for a specific branch for example?

Comment: Yes - just have separate build definitions for each branch.  We do precisely this with a code-promotion branch plan, where we have automated deployment to different environments for each branch.